# Is it possible to run JShell like REPL on GraalVM 19.11?

Tags: graalvm

I tried to execute few lines of Java and JavaScript codes on GraalVM. i used REPL for JavaScript and node. it works awesome but i couldn't find jshell REPL to run java code.
when i refer https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/ document. i see below way to run java code.

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ java HelloWorld
```

**GraalVM 19.1.1 is based on JDK version 8u222**, whereas jshell was introduced since JDK 9. I hope only in future GraalVM can accommodate jshell REPL.

Is it possible to run jshell REPL on GraalVM? is there any other tool available to run jshell REPL on GraalVM?

Comment: GraalVM 19.1.1 is based on JDK version 8u222 and there's no jshell in jdk8, you're very correct. Can you please clarify do you mean run jshell REPL on GraalVM, cause that can mean different things like running jshell from a GraalVM distribution? Run jshell as a GraalVM native image? Run jshell with the GraalVM compiler as the top tier JIT?